# Is there a way to place number on the center of the screen in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am working with pygame, to display the score I have images from 0 to 9 and need to place them centralized, but i can't just put it in the middle because the size of the score can change, the only solution I found until now is to hardcode it for scores up to 9, then up to 99 etc like in the code below

```
if len(str(self.value)) == 1:
    win.blit(self.imgs[self.value],
             ((x - self.imgs[self.value].get_width(), y)))

elif len(str(self.value)) == 2:
    win.blit(self.imgs[int(str(self.value)[0])],
             (x - self.imgs[int(str(self.value)[0])].get_width(), y))
    win.blit(self.imgs[int(str(self.value)[1])],
             (x, y))
```

Is there a generic way to do display n numbers centralized looping for all the numbers of the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the image ([`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)) by [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). Set the center of the rectangle by an keyword attribute (`center = (x, y)`) and use the rectangle to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image:

```py
centered_rect = self.imgs[self.value].get_rect(center = (x, y))
win.blit(self.imgs[self.value], centered_rect)
```